# How to deserialize Java Objects with RDFBeans and Apache Jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena

## Question / Problem

I've easily managed to deserialize Objects with simple properties (e.g. of type String). However when there is a link to another Type, it is not automatically resolved and I get an exception. It seems the link is not resolved, but handled as simple URI-property.

**How can I automatically deserialize the whole object-graph?**

## Update 1

From debugging I know, an element is resolved by querying the triple-store for a certain predicate, so when manually adding these lines before reading the file, the `SubGeographicalRegion` can be unmarshalled as JavaBean.

```
  Class<SubGeographicalRegion> class1 = SubGeographicalRegion.class;
  URI class1RdfType = RDFBeanInfo.get(class1).getRDFType();
  PlainLiteral class1Literal = model.createPlainLiteral(class1.getName());
  model.addStatement(class1RdfType, RDFBeanManager.BINDINGCLASS_PROPERTY, class1Literal);
```

However, it seems there is a new object created, even when there is a reference to only one and the same SubGeographicalRegion.

## Update 2

Implementing `hashCode()` and `equals()` based on the element's ID solves the problem of multiple instances!

## Code

RDF/XML file (excerpt):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#">
 <cim:SubGeographicalRegion rdf:ID="_93ed4cbc90fe424caa7f572e9652997">
  <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>SubRegion</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
  <cim:SubGeographicalRegion.Region rdf:resource="#_a56f739020054bcd826f675918ab2df"/>
 </cim:SubGeographicalRegion>
 <cim:Substation rdf:ID="_da9f289336dd46bdac22c961b7b525f3">
  <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>73109E0009</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
  <cim:Substation.Region rdf:resource="#_93ed4cbc90fe424caa7f572e9652997"/>
 </cim:Substation>
 <cim:Substation rdf:ID="_e66d0514110841c285b7956c98e52b32">
  <cim:IdentifiedObject.name>73019J0003</cim:IdentifiedObject.name>
  <cim:Substation.Region rdf:resource="#_93ed4cbc90fe424caa7f572e9652997"/>
 </cim:Substation>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Substation.java:

```
@RDFBean("http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#Substation")
public class Substation {

  private String id;
  private String name;
  private SubGeographicalRegion subRegion;

  @RDFSubject
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @RDF("http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#IdentifiedObject.name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @RDF("http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#Substation.Region")
  public SubGeographicalRegion getSubRegion() {
    return subRegion;
  }

  public void setSubRegion(SubGeographicalRegion subRegion) {
    this.subRegion = subRegion;
  }
}
```

SubGeographicalRegion.java:

```
@RDFBean("http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#SubGeographicalRegion")
public class SubGeographicalRegion {

  private String id;
  private String name;

  private Collection<Substation> substations;

  @RDF("http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#IdentifiedObject.name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @RDFSubject(prefix = "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#ID")
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  // this works, but returns a HashSet<URI>
  @RDF(inverseOf = "http://iec.ch/TC57/2010/CIM-schema-cim15#Substation.Region")
  public Collection<Substation> getSubstations() {
    return substations;
  }

  public void setSubstations(Collection<Substation> substations) {
    this.substations = substations;
  }
}
```

Hint: the method `SubGeographicalRegion.getSubstations()` returns a `HashSet<URI>` (despite it is declared as `Collection<Substation>`)

And here is how I start the engine:

```
org.ontoware.rdf2go.model.Model model = RDF2Go.getModelFactory().createModel();
model.open();

// try-catch omitted for readability
model.readFrom(getClass().getResourceAsStream(RDF_XML_INPUT_FILENAME), Syntax.RdfXml);

RDFBeanManager rdfBeanManager = new RDFBeanManager(model);
ClosableIterator<Substation> substationIterator = rdfBeanManager.getAll(Substation.class);
while (substationIterator.hasNext()) {
  logger.info("substation.name: ", substationIterator.next().getName());
}

model.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated as Update 1 in my original post, the solution is to add some (!) of the binding classes manually. I couldn't find out, why this is necessary, nor why it is necessary for some of the classes, while it works fine for others.

(so it's more of a workaround, then)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using either [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/) or [Sesame](http://rdf4j.org) directly instead of RDF2Go, which no longer appears to be maintained.

If you don't mind using (some of) the Sesame API, you might try [Pinto](https://github.com/complexible/pinto).

Comment: You wrote that lib for me? I'm flattered. However, since I want to read collections of objects, pinto seems not to support that.

Comment: is this what you want? https://github.com/Complexible/pinto/blob/develop/test/src/com/complexible/pinto/RDFMapperTests.java#L278-L292

Comment: I don't think so. In _RDFBeans_ it is: `rdfBeanManager.getAll(Substation.class);` what returns an iterator over (or a collection of) substations.

Comment: sure.  RDFBeans has some overlap with Empire, which would support that type of call